# I want to load my data from mysql to sqlite

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

is it possible to connecct, or to copy the data from mysql to sqlite? I just need to store the data from mysql to sqlite.

I used mysql because im working on an online app in android and for updating puposes. i want to copy the data from mysql to sqlite so my android app will still run even there is no internet and because of that sqlite database.

please help. thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achive here. Do you want the SQLite database to hold data while the system is offline and send it back later? Do you want to be able to distribute the populated sqlite database as part of an application? Do you just want to publish data from some central mysql database to multipe clients using sqlite? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect your application with my sql server, you can use some rest service to connect with database, and return results to the calling application.

Check examples of creating, consuming rest php service by following link:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

By these methods you can fetch data from a mysql server, further to create and perform database operation on a device database use following link:

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842

Comment: the link have full code, and for exporting and importing you need to use tools only

Comment: can you further explain how and where is that tool?

Comment: Im just really new to android.

Comment: I have this project. to create a custom calendar and alert if there is an event with the specific date, so i used mysql if ever there is update it will update online, and im starting to load it in sqlite so even there is no internet the calendar will still alert.